# Nested ARM template and dependsOn

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am creating set of NSG rules with my ARM template and trying to update subnets to use these NSG rules in nested ARM template. Template deployments fails with "Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress". I tried to use the "dependsOn" feature within the nested template but that does not do the trick. I have tried to give the NSG name and the resourceId()

`"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]",`

to dependsOn without luck. Is there better way for waiting for the NSG rules to be ready before trying to update the subnets?

Template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "NSGName": parameters('subnetName')
    "ResourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-11-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('NSGName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "Allow-Inbound-RDP",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "3389",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "192.168.0.1/24",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 4050,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
      "name": "apply-nsg-to-subnet",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode" : "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion" : "2018-03-01",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
              "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "[reference(resourceId(variables('ResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetName'), parameters('subnetName')), '2018-03-01').addressPrefix]",
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe that one NSG and one subnet update would go fine through but it does not when I did it with eight.

Comment: can you post that other template for me, please? meanwhile,here's the example https://paste.ee/p/1t3Ci. its using AV set, but it doesnt matter, just make NESTED deployment depend on the NSG

Comment: well, your template worked for me without issues, apart from a bunch of typos everywhere

Comment: I have to admit it took about 7 minutes for something this small, which is weird, can you try tomorrow, might be a temporary problem. But I dont see anything wrong with your approach. unless you have a bunch of `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets` in the nested template. in this case they shouldn't run in parallel. one must depend on the other to form a sequence

Comment: ok that might be the problem since I have quite many time that "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets" as I am updating those subnets one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your nested deployment itself needs to depend on that ( the other nested deployment), this means that you need to add:

`[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]`.

Inside deployment resources can NOT depend on anything outside of deployment (and since its nested everything in the parent is outside of it).

Comment: If I do that I get "The resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/testnsg' is not defined in the template"

Comment: no, your NESTED DEPLOYMENT needs to depend on that, not subnet\vnet INSIDE nested deployment

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. I put that resourceid on the top level of the nested deployment. However, that does not seem to work because I get the "another operation..."

Comment: I have added the nested template here. Do you think you would need the parent template as well?

Comment: yeah post that please if i cant get it through to you :). you need to move that `dependsOn` to the parent template

Comment: Here you go. This is pretty standard stuff I am working with. I am not just getting the nested template.

Comment: I have several subnets being affected by the nested template so putting dependsOn on them as well solved the problem.